# emacs dired and openwith

Tags: emacs, elisp, dired

I want to configure emacs to use external applications 
when I open image files from dired mode.

On the other hand, I also want to use inline images in emacs buffers.

To open files in external applications I use [**openwith.el**](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0225855/misc/openwith.el) 
package http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OpenWith

The problem with the openwith minor mode is that it is
global and when it is enabled by a dired-mode-hook

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq truncate-lines t)
            (openwith-mode t)
            ))
```

it acts everywhere and all inline images in emacs buffers
are opened in external applications.

I tried to change

```
:global t
```

to

```
:global nil
```

in the [**openwith.el**](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0225855/misc/openwith.el), but it somehow disables openwith mode completely.

So, my question is: How to tell emacs to use openwith minor mode only
with dired buffer and not anywhere else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The way openwith-mode works is a bit peculiar: it really assumes that you use it either globally or not at all. What you want here, however, is to use it locally, namely only from within a dired buffer.

That cannot be achieved very easily, but here is a way.

Open your the source file of openwith-mode, *openwith.el*. Then scroll all the way down until you get to the definition of the actual minor mode. Then *comment out* that definition by placing a semicolon at the beginning of each line:

```
;;;###autoload
; (define-minor-mode openwith-mode
;   "Automatically open files with external programs."
;   :lighter ""
;   :global t
;   (if openwith-mode
;       (progn
;         ;; register `openwith-file-handler' for all files
;         (put 'openwith-file-handler 'safe-magic t)
;         (put 'openwith-file-handler 'operations '(insert-file-contents))
;         (add-to-list 'file-name-handler-alist '("" . openwith-file-handler)))
;     (setq file-name-handler-alist
;           (delete '("" . openwith-file-handler) file-name-handler-alist))))
```

Then underneath this code (but before `(provide 'openwith)`), insert the following code:

```
(defvar openwith-mode nil)

(mapc (lambda (function) 
        (ad-add-advice function 
                       '(dired-openwith nil t (advice . (lambda () (let ((openwith-mode t)) ad-do-it))))
                       'around 0))
      '(dired-find-alternate-file 
        dired-find-file 
        dired-find-file-other-window
        dired-mouse-find-file-other-window
        dired-view-file))

(put 'openwith-file-handler 'safe-magic t)
(put 'openwith-file-handler 'operations '(insert-file-contents))
(add-to-list 'file-name-handler-alist '("" . openwith-file-handler))
```

This code does a few things.

First, it defines a variable called openwith-mode. This variable is used inside one of the functions of openwith-mode that decides whether to use an external application or not. Normally, a variable like that is provided automatically by Emacs when you define a minor-mode -- however since we just commented out the definition of the actual minor mode above, we explicitly re-introduce this variable here.

The purpose of the variable is to work as a kind of switch through which we can control whether or not an image file should be inlined or passed to an external viewer.

Next we have the `(mapc ...)` expression. What we do here is iterate over a list of five functions:

- dired-find-alternate-file
- dired-find-file
- dired-find-file-other-window
- dired-mouse-find-file-other-window
- dired-view-file

which are functions dired provides for opening a file. To each of these function we add a small amount of code in a technique called [advising](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html): what `(ad-add-advice...)` does is set the variable `openwith-mode` to `t` whenever one of these five functions is called. Outside of the function call, the variable remains set to `nil`.

This has the effect that whenever you use one of dired's functions to open a file, the function of openwith-mode that is responsible for calling external applications sees the variable set to `t` and promptly tries to open an external application if it knows one. 
The reason we have to jump through such hoops is that the same openwith-mode function is also called whenever you open an image file using <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> - that's just the way openwith-mode is implemented.

(NB: unfortunately we cannot just use the current major-mode as a switch because this will be the major-mode of a new buffer that will have been created already for the file to open. It is always `fundamental-mode`.)

Finally, the last three lines are just copy & paste from the minor-mode definition we commented out before. They say that the function I've been mentioning a lot already and that is responsible for calling external applications -- called `open-with-filehandler` -- is a so-called file-handler. It does not really do anything special for actual access to the file, hence we're setting `safe-magic` for that function to `t`. Also, we declare that the operation `insert-file-contents` is handled by our function in a non-trivial way. (See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Magic-File-Names.html) for more information on these properties.)

And at the very last, we actually install the file handler.

---

**Important**: The openwith-mode documenation recommends that you put the following two lines into your .emacs file:

```
(require 'openwith)
(openwith-mode t)
```

Now that there is no minor-mode `openwith-mode` any more (after we commented its definition out), please make sure that you remove the second line, e.g. by commenting it out too:

```
;; (openwith-mode t)
```

After re-starting Emacs, if you open an image file with dired, it should open in an external application; if you open it via <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> it will be inlined in a buffer.

Comment: Upvoted, but you haven't explained why you needed to comment out the mode definition (or directly modify the library at all -- `eval-after-load` would be a more normal approach to adding that extra code).

Comment: @phils good point - I only made a small comment about that, but it wasn't very clear: The way openwith-mode is designed, it's meant to be either on or of *globally*: it adds a global file-handler and when the mode is on, that file-handler checks for external applications, if it is off, it does nothing.

Comment: But would you not achieve the same result by using `eval-after-load` to wrap `(fmakunbound 'openwith-mode)` and the rest of your code, and not actually touch the original library?

Comment: @phils Oh, I see what you mean. Yes, you're right, that should work. (I can see pros and cons for either approach though.)

Answer (score 4):

I don't use `openwith`. I use the function defined at

http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_dired_open_file_in_ext_apps.html

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to set emacsclient as preferred program for the filetypes you like in `openwith-associations` in openwith.el and start using emacsclient.

You could start new emacs session every time but that sounds uglier than the previous suggestion.